# Clamp BigInteger into a long

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert a Java `BigInteger` into a `long`, clamping it to the range of `long`? I mean, if it's larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` or smaller than `Long.MIN_VALUE`, use these edge values, otherwise use the exact value.

Comment: There is `BigInteger.longValueExact()` that throws an ArithmeticException on overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this custom function:

```
public static long clampToLong(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.bitLength() <= 63) {
        return val.longValue();
    }
    return val.signum() == 1 ? Long.MAX_VALUE : Long.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: `longValue()` can return a value with an opposite sign so your last check for `signum()` introduces inconsistent behaviour. I'd just use `longValue()` TBH.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Obviously if the OP wanted behaviour consistent with `longValue()` then they would be using `longValue()`.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, not, if there are up to 63 bits.